# How to write a SQL query that will Count two types of values in the Same Column of one Table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table name 'demo' with fields id(PK), user and item with below data:

```
id  user item
==  ==== =====
1   anuj    A
2   anuj    A
3   anuj    A
4   anuj    B
5   anuj    B
6   anuj    B
7   patil   A
8   patil   A
9   patil   A
10  rahul   B
11  rahul   B
12  tanmay  A
13  tanmay  A
```

Now I want to write a query which will give me result like this:

```
User   Count of A    Count of B
====   ==========    ===========
anuj   3             3
patil  3             0
rahul  0             2
tanmay 2             0
```

Basically is this possible?  I have tried but not successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Conditional Aggregate`

`Case statement` inside the `count` aggregate will produce either `1` or `NULL`. Since the `NULL` values are eliminated by aggregate functions the count will consider the value to count only when condition is satisfied

```
select User,    
      Count(case when item = 'A' then 1 end) as `Count of A`,
      Count(case when item = 'B' then 1 end) as `Count of B`
From yourtable
Group by User
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick help..  But above query is giving Syntax error.

Comment: @Raj - There was a extra comma. Updated check now

Comment: Great!! Worked like a charm!  Thanks a lot... :)

Comment: Just wanted to know will this work in **sqlite** also?

Answer (score 2):

```
select
user,
sum(if(item="A",1,0)) as "count of A",
sum(if(item="B",1,0)) as "count of B"
from
demo
group by user;
```